# Переход на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, html

Кто подскажет, какие команды позволят открыть в новых вкладках все ссылки на странице, ну или пару, может цикл какой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, il = a.length; i < il; ++i){
    window.open(a[i].href);
}
```

Открывает окна для всех ссылок `<a>`. Да, и для счетчиков тоже. =)